# Approximating square root for long expressions

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I'm currently working on a problem which asks me to calculate the potential energy of a three spring system arranged in an equilateral triangle constrained to move in the x-y plane.  As a consequence of solving the problem, I've come a cross a multi-term expression inside of a square root and am unsure how to approximate it to proceed further.  I'm familiar with using Taylor Series to approximate series such as:
$$(1+x)^\alpha  = \sum_{n=o}^\infty{\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n}$$

The current expression, however, is of the form:
$$\sqrt{l^2 + 2l(x_2-x_1)+x_2^2+x_1^2-2x_1x_2+y_1^2+y_2^2-2y_1y_2}$$
where $l$ is a constant.

Is there an alternate form of Taylor Series I can use to address this?  Or do I need to manipulate the expression further before I can apply approximation methods?

Comment: Which approximation or final form depends on what you want to do with it later. The expression is also equal to $\sqrt{(l+x_2-x_1)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$, but who knows if it is better this way or not.

Comment: Looking to approximate the terms $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ to second order so that I can take the gradient to find the associated forces.  After that I will use Matlab to find the eigenfrequencies of the system.

Yes, that was the original form - I distributed in the hope that it would help me see a way to approximate more easily.